# Msgbox is not getting displayed in outlookApp_Send event

Tags: vba, outlook

I am sending mail using outlook, on send event I am trying to display message, but msgbox is not getting displayed till I clicked on screen( anywhere).
(Once user click on Send in Outlook, I am changing the Outlook windowState to minimize.)

```
Public Sub oApp_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    If(StrComp(clickedEvent, "ClickMe", vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
        MsgBox "HI"
    end if
End sub
```

Thanks

Comment: 1) What's the "clickedEvent"   2) You are yourself checking the condition of clicked event before showing the message box..

Comment: @NitinSingh yes

Comment: So unless the "clickedEvent" matches, the messagebox will not be shown.. That's what the code's doing.  First set the app to be activated and then remove the check.

Comment: @NitinSingh condition is always true in above case. anyway I got the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with several MS Office applications. Try adding this code and see if it helps:

```
AppActivate Application.Caption
```

or

```
AppActivate "Microsoft Excel" ' name of application that needs to be in focus
```

From the documentation:

> The [AppActivate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/appactivate-statement) statement changes the focus to the named
>   application or window but does not affect whether it is maximized or
>   minimized.